# How to effectively train this JavaScript neural network (vanilla code, no frameworks or libraries)

Tags: javascript, machine-learning, neural-network

I was having a quick look at neural networks for the first time, and started following: [Let's code a neural network in plain JavaScript](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0zVEGEvSaeGmPpG8tAaqSmf3k56LPwiF). The code demo [is here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mpj/neural-network-from-scratch-part-1), it trains a perceptron(?) to determine if the SVG points are in team #1 or team #2. During training, this is the code to specify which team a point is in:

```js
return point.x > point.y ? 1 : -1
```

The visualisation uses colour to differentiate teams.

[image: team differences]

I tried to change the team logic to this:

```
if ((point.x > 100 && point.x < 300) && ( point.y > 100 && point.y < 300 )) {
    return -1;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

Which I thought would've resulted in a visualisation like this:

[image: expected visualisation]

But instead I got inconsistent results [like this](https://umaar.github.io/neural-network-from-scratch/). Code is [on GitHub](https://github.com/umaar/neural-network-from-scratch/blob/cd170cd55bb692de4f4728c7aa3db945c3daf964/main.js#L6-L16). I don't fully understand why this is happening, any ideas?

Side note: One of the comments from the YouTube videos linked above suggests:

> ...i'm not familiar with NN or AI, but when you teach your NN you should
>   probably correct rate for each learning iteration. For example, i'd
>   increment it untill weights will be enough to correct wrong answer
>   from NN. Then rate you choose as 0.1 will be more meaningful...

They're referring to the learning rate in this formula:

```
function train(weights, point, actualTeam) {
    const team = guess(weights, point); // 1
    const error = actualTeam - team;
    const learningRate = 0.1;

    return {
        x: weights.x + point.x * error * learningRate,
        y: weights.y + point.y * error * learningRate
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on this?

There's a good chance I'm missing some elementary understanding here. I started playing around with that demo because it looked interesting, but will definitely have to read up more on neural networks to progress. Thanks for helping!